# Duplicated column name in a Dataframe. row bind the duplicated column together

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

I have a Dataframe with more than 60-70 column name.
in this 60-70 ,most of the column name are duplicated.

I want to row bind the duplicated column together.
How to find out the duplicated column name and add the row to the column respectively.

Finally,the dataframe must be a unequal row dataframe.(Fillthe empty cell by NA).
Thank you

Comment: Try the bind_rows function from the dplyr  package.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Many, seeking to help, are limited absent `data/code tried/desired result` that will surely find their way to your future questions. Welcome again.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

By default, `data.frame` doesn't allow duplicate column names whereas `matrix` allows.  If it is a `data.frame`, then probably the duplicates may be changed by suffixing `.1`, `.2`, etc.

An option is to use `split.default` on the column names (to avoid any issues, just remove the suffix part (if any) with `sub`) into a `list`, then `unlist` the `list` element and convert to a `data.frame` after appending `NA`s at the end

```
lst1 <- lapply(split.default(df1, sub("\\.\\d+$", "", names(df1))), unlist)
mx <- max(lengths(lst1))
data.frame(lapply(lst1, `length<-`, mx))
```